# How can I use google maps of old version layers?

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

I would implement in my app a functionality to see the same place in the past years and I don't found any response at this question. Anybody know how to use for example google hybrid layer for a past years? It can be implemented with Openlayers or Google API?

I'm tried to find a solution for this problem but for doesn't find something. I saw that in google earth in implemented something like this but for very old maps.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API has no longer support for OpenLayer as of 2019. But still there is a way to use Google API key, see this example: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps